# python recursion avoid result as global variable

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

```
res_dict = {}

def get_value(co , passed_dict ):

    for k, v in passed_dict.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            get_value(co, v)
        else:
            res_dict[k] = v
            print("from else",res_dict)

    return res_dict


def easy():

    inner_dict = {
                    "test1" : {"test1_in" : "abc"},
                    "test2" : {"test1_in" : "xyz"}
                  }
    dict1 = {}
    count = 0
    val_from_function= {}
    key_list = ['key1','key2']

    for key in key_list:
        count = count + 1
        val_from_function = get_value(count ,inner_dict)
        print("before assign" ,dict1 )
        dict1[key] = val_from_function
        print("after assign" , dict1)

    # dict1['key1'] = {'test1' : "abc"}
    # dict1['key2'] = {'test1' :  "xyz"}

    print(dict1)

easy()
```

- receiving output : {'key1': {'test1_in': 'xyz'}, 'key2': {'test1_in': 'xyz'}}
- expected o/p : {'key1': {'test1_in': 'abc'}, 'key2': {'test1_in': 'xyz'}}
- I understand the value of dict1 is updated with the last value as res_dict declared as global 
  variable.
- I can solve it by appending the inner key value with outer key and then storing in dictionary.
- I might solve it using ordered dictionary.
- taking keys from list as outer key value (key1, key2 ..,key3000) is unknown.

Looking for suggestions on how to make this code better with expected o/p.
Have 3k key-pair values, same as sample pattern with more nested k,v & storing o/p as cache, so performance is not a very big issue here.

Answer (score 0):

```
# This modifies passed_dict


def get_value(passed_dict, recur_dict_new={}, isInitial=True):

    for k, v in passed_dict.items():
        if isInitial:
            recur_dict_new = {}
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            temp = get_value(v, recur_dict_new, isInitial=False)
            passed_dict[k]= temp
        else:
            recur_dict_new[k]=v

    return recur_dict_new


def easy():

    inner_dict = {
                    "test1" : {"test1_in" : "abc"},
                    "test2" : {"test1_in" : "xyz"}
                  }

    key_list = ['key1','key2']

    for key in key_list:
        get_value(inner_dict)
    # dict1['key1'] = {'test1' : "abc"}
    # dict1['key2'] = {'test1' :  "xyz"}

    print(inner_dict)

easy()
```

> Thanks for looking, I have solved with one of the ways as mentioned above, 
>   tested with 15k records with 3 more levels of nested JSON, the performance was okay(4ms)

- O/p : {'test1': {'test1_in': 'abc'}, 'test2': {'test1_in': 'xyz'}}